# Available Input/output AVAudioSession data sources in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, ios6, avaudiosession

I am using AVAudioSession and remote IO with the aim of record some info throught both the audio jack connector and the built-in mic...
I guess it could be possible with the new feature of iOS 6: Multiroute audio.

In order to do that I would like to get the inputDataSources from my audio session: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute)

What I am doing is:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSArray *available_outputs = [session inputDataSources];
```

(I am also configuring the audio session and activating it)

What I get is all zeros in `available_outputs`...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to do something else with the data sources but I get zero count sources as well - works on iOS 7, but not on 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/inputDataSources):

> This currently only applies to certain USB devices.

This API is going to change in iOS 7, but 6 is limited to that obscure definition of "certain USB devices".
BTW, from my tests - it worked on iOS 6.02 for the iPhone microphone but not on 6.1.4 (both tests on iPhone 5).